# How can I get crash reports with TestFlight in iTunes Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight, crash-reports

With the old version (TestflightApp.com), there was a friendly interface to get crash reports. But now, I can't find the crash information in iTunes Connect.

Does Apple no longer support this? will they support it ?
Is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the release update for the newest Xcode Beta:

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=02232015d

After you install the latest beta you can then see crashes reported in the organizer view which can be accessed window -> organizer in Xcode's menu bar.